# how to pass processed data back from slave to master using chunking

Tags: java, spring-batch, chunking, remote-process

I was able to repeat example of [remote chunking](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotechunking):

master:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableBatchIntegration
@EnableIntegration
@PropertySource("classpath:remote-chunking.properties")
public class MasterConfiguration {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterConfiguration.class);
    @Value("${broker.url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private RemoteChunkingMasterStepBuilderFactory masterStepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(this.brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (requests going to workers)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(requests())
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("requests"))
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure inbound flow (replies coming from workers)
     */
    @Bean
    public QueueChannel replies() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("replies"))
                .channel(replies())
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure master step components
     */
    @Bean
    public ListItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskletStep masterStep() {
        return this.masterStepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(2)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .outputChannel(requests())
                .inputChannel(replies())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job remoteChunkingJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("remoteChunkingJobNew")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(masterStep())
                .build();
    }

}
```

slave:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableBatchIntegration
@EnableIntegration
@PropertySource("classpath:remote-chunking.properties")
public class WorkerConfiguration {

    @Value("${broker.url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RemoteChunkingWorkerBuilder<Integer, Integer> remoteChunkingWorkerBuilder;

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(this.brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Configure inbound flow (requests coming from the master)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("requests"))
                .channel(requests())
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (replies going to the master)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel replies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(replies())
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("replies"))
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure worker components
     */
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> itemProcessor() {
        return item -> {
            System.out.println("processing item " + item);
            return item;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (Integer item : items) {
                System.out.println("writing item " + item);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow workerIntegrationFlow() {
        return this.remoteChunkingWorkerBuilder
                .itemProcessor(itemProcessor())
                .itemWriter(itemWriter())
                .inputChannel(requests())
                .outputChannel(replies())
                .build();
    }

}
```

But now I want to pass processed data back to master. How can I achieve it?

**P.S.**

My up to date code: [here](https://github.com/gredwhite/spring-batch-remote-execution)

Comment: I think that example might be focusing on the configuration part, not the doing part and that is why it uses a throwaway channel (`requests()`). See https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/dsl/IntegrationFlow.html (and perhaps https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/dsl/IntegrationFlowDefinition.html, about what else you could do there, handle/transform/route, etc.)

Comment: @tevemadar I am looking for more concrete pieces of advices. Could provide some steps how to achieve what I want?